# PWM not found in Occidentalis v0.2

Tags: pwm, occidentalis

I'm trying to get my DC motor to work according to [this tutorial from Adafruit](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-lesson-9-controlling-a-dc-motor/software):

I'm running **Occidentalis v0.2** (from day 1, which was some 4 months ago) and never had a similar issue.
This is the problem:

```
$ sudo ls /sys/class/rpi-pwm
ls: cannot access /sys/class/rpi-pwm: No such file or directory
```

Also:

```
$ ls -lR /sys/class | grep -c rpi-pwm
0
```

Seems PWM kernel module is not installed!? How come and how can I fix that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem after doing an update. The entire pwm and servo module has disappeared. Maybe because it is a kernel module and the update pulled in a new (non-occidentalis kernel).

Anyway, I fixed it by putting the old kernel back. You can find instructions on how to do that in the [details page for Occicentalis v.02](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-raspberry-pi-educational-linux-distro/occidentalis-v0-dot-2), last section at the bottom: Kernel Source.

Basically you need to download their [Kernel+Modules tgz file](http://adafruit-raspberry-pi.s3.amazonaws.com/OccidentalisV02Kernel.tgz), extract it and install it by copying the files:

- **tar -zxvf mykernel.tgz**
- **sudo cp tmp/kernel.img /boot/**
- **sudo cp -R tmp/modules/lib/* /lib/**
- **rm -rf tmp**

Then reboot and /sys/class/rpi-pwm should be present again.

Comment: Sounds sensible. I'll check it and let you know.

Comment: Great walkthrough, @Whiskey. New output: `sudo ls /sys/class/rpi-pwm
pwm0`. Now I just have to remember what I needed that 4 months ago for ^_^